# How to find value difference of two struct instances in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two instances from the same struct in Swift. I need to find out key-values that have the same keys but different values.

For example:

```swift
struct StructDemo {
    let shopId: Int
    let template: String?

}

let a = StructDemo(shopId: 3, template: "a")
let a = StructDemo(shopId: 3, template: "different a")

// My expectation is to return the change pairs
let result = [template: "different a"]
```

My approach is as show below but comes errors.

```swift
static func difference(left: StructDemo, right: StructDemo) -> [String: Any]{
        var result:[String: Any] = [:]
        for leftItem in Mirror(reflecting: left).children {
            guard let key = leftItem.label else { continue }
            let value = leftItem.value
            if value != right[key] { // This is the problem. Errror message: Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'RawRepresentable'
                result[key] = right[key]
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Appreciate for any suggestion and solutions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are seeing is that you referred to

```
right[key]
```

but `right` is a `StructDemo` and is not subscriptable. You can't look up fields given a runtime name. Well, you can with `Mirror` which you correctly used for `left`, but you did not mirror `right`.

Using `Mirror` will lead to other issues, as you will have expressions with static type `Any` where `Equatable` will be required in order to compare values.

IMHO, your best bet is to avoid a generic, reflective approach, and just embrace static typing and write a custom difference functions that iterates all the known fields of your type. Hard coding is not so bad here, if there is only one struct type that you are trying to diff.

If you have a handful of struct types each needing diffs then that might be a different story, but I don't know a good way to get around the need for `Equatable`. But if you have a ton of diffable types, maybe you want dictionaries to begin with?